List of references for quantum algorithms for optimization problems
I have to perform a bibliography review on all quantum algorithms available for mainly optimization problems, whether or not they can run now (NISQ) or at FTQC era.
This review includes "pure" quantum algorithms as well as quantum heuristics like variational quantum algorithms and, is limited to gate based quantum computers.
I know the QAOA algorithm, it seems the VQE and Grover algorithms can also be used in optimization processes, some optimization problems can also be turned into a linear system of equations, so HHL could also be useful.
But I am sure there are several other algorithms, probably less known.
Do you have a general overview of quantum algorithms I should study ?

A recent survey paper

In this talk, Ronald de Wolf surveys quantum speed-ups for both discrete and continuous optimization.
And here is the slide deck.
